# Make label reference contain section number

Tags: enumitem, cleveref

I have some code that looks like

```
\section*{Problem 1}

\begin{enumerate}
   \item Hello
   \item \label{problem-2b} Yes
   \item \cref{problem-2b} Welp
\end{enumerate}
```

I want the reference to appear as

```
problem 1a)
```

as a refference. **How can I include the name of the previous section into the reference?** I already have the exercise number as a counter.

For a "MWE" of my actual problem see below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %Neccecary for ifthenelse

\usepackage{enumitem}


\newcounter{tittel}
\setcounter{tittel}{0}

\newcounter{prob}[tittel]
\setcounter{prob}{0}

\newcounter{alternative}[prob]
\setcounter{alternative}{0}

\newcounter{alfa}[prob]

 \newif\iffirstalt

 \NewDocumentCommand{\Oppgave}{s o}{   %
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
   {\refstepcounter{alternative}\iffirstalt\else\refstepcounter{prob}\firstalttrue\fi}%
   {\setcounter{alternative}{0}\refstepcounter{prob}\firstaltfalse}%
  \section*{Oppgave~\arabic{prob}~% 
  \label{\arabic{tittel}.\arabic{prob}}
    {\normalfont\IfBooleanTF{#1}{Alternativ \Roman{alternative}~}{}}%
                \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\normalfont\normalsize (#2~poeng)}}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave~\arabic{prob}} \refstepcounter{alfa} 
}

\makeatletter

\let\org@item\@item
\def\myspecial@item[#1]{%
  \org@item[#1]%
  \ifdef\@listctr
  {%
    \expandafter\ifdefequal\@listctr\@enumctr
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\hspace{0.8em}\textbf{\alph{alfa})}}
    \label{\arabic{tittel}.\arabic{prob}.\alph{alfa}}
    \refstepcounter{alfa}}%
    {}%
  }{}%
}

\newenvironment{oppgaver}{%
  \begin{enumerate}[ref={\alph{alfa}},topsep =1.2em,label=\textbf{\alph{alfa})},labelsep=1.5em,itemsep=0.7cm]
  \let\@item\myspecial@item
}{%
  \end{enumerate}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\hypersetup{
    linktoc=all,            % Link all the things in the toc
    colorlinks=true,        % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
}

\usepackage[norsk, nameinlink, noabbrev]{cleveref}

\crefname{alfa}{oppgave}{oppgave}
\Crefname{alfa}{Oppgave}{Oppgave}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\stepcounter{tittel}

\Oppgave[4] % Oppgave 1

\begin{oppgaver}
    \item Prob 1

    \item \label{prob1b} Prob 2

    \item \cref{prob1b} Prob 3
\end{oppgaver}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `\section*`? Change the section format to use "Problem" so that you have access to the regular section counter.

Comment: Your first code example is rather incomplete while your second one is not very minimal. This is why I basically just answered the question title. Could you make a true MWE that will be helpful to others finding this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by redefining `\p@enumi`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*\p@enumi{\thesection.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Some Section}

\begin{enumerate}
   \item Hello
   \item \label{some-item} Yes
   \item Bye
\end{enumerate}

Look at item~\ref{some-item}

\end{document}
```